# How can I add a AppBarButton icon to a normal button in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How can I add a AppBarButton icon to a normal button in Windows Phone 8.1?

At the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx) you can see the AppBarButton icons in use.  How can I do the same or similar as that with a normal button?

```
<Button>
    <ICON HERE SOMEHOW />
    <TextBlock Content="Click Me!" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app bar icons are just characters from Segoe UI Symbol font. Just create a text block with that font and select the icon you need (you can use app called Character Map that comes with Windows)

Answer (score 0):

With the windows phone 8.0 apps, when I add a button to the app bar it actually adds an image file to the assets folder. Add the button you need to an appbar, add the icon you need. Reference the image as you normally would and then delete the application bar from your page. If this is a silverlight app you can do that.